# theme.res file does not open anymore, codename one themes

Tags: codenameone

Themes.res file is not opening.
[image]

What do i do ?

However, the app is working.

The exception that I am getting on the console while opening the file is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.createImage(Resources.java:936)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.createImage(EditableResources.java:2332)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.loadFont(Resources.java:1119)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.loadFont(EditableResources.java:1932)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.openFileWithXMLSupport(EditableResources.java:426)
    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorView$LoadResourceFileAction.exectute(ResourceEditorView.java:4112)
    at com.codename1.ui.resource.util.BlockingAction.run(BlockingAction.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there any way I can recover this file / data ?

Answer (score 0):

First verify that the file isn't a 0 size file, if it got corrupted to that level you will need to restore from backup. This hasn't happened for us in years as far as I know but its always a risk.

Next make sure you didn't remove/rename any ttf fonts that might be used by the theme, this is a common cause for failures in the designer.

Next we need to see the actual error and to do that we need to run the designer from command line using:

```
java -jar ~/.codenameone/designer_1.jar
```

(code for Mac/Linux replace ~ with your home directory and reverse the slashes for Windows).

Now try to open the resource file and see if you get an exception in the console. Assuming you do we will know more about it and might be able to help you recover your data.

We are currently migrating to new [XML based format](http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/08/teamwork-and-other-things.html) which should become the default soon.

Comment: The file isn't a zero size. I was removing / renaming ttf fonts. I am sure this was the cause. I will run the command and post the error. The XML based format is highly awaited :)

Comment: I have edited the question with the error that I got on the console. Is there any way I can recover my file ?

Comment: It seems that the xml support is enabled on your machine and the xml file seems to be corrupt. Try disabling the XML mode then open the file again.

Comment: FYI this seems to be related to your usage of legacy fonts which don't work well in the XML mode. You should remove everything from the font section. You can also edit the xml to remove all legacyFont entries.